# Shopify variable to get customer email in thank you page

Tags: variables, shopify

Is there a way to get the customer email in the thank you page of shopify?

In their documentation I found this

{{Shopify.checkout.email}}

But it won't work, an empty string is returned

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify variable you are using is a Javascript Variable. Try using the customer object to get the email.

```
{{ customer.email }}
```

More information on customer object - [Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/customer)

If you do not have access to edit the Thank You page and are pasting code in the **Settings->Checkout->Additional Scripts** then use javascript code like below.

```
var email = Shopify.checkout.email;
```

Comment: is the Shopify.checkout is guaranteed to be always available? I ran into the case where it's available on some Thank you pages but not on others

Comment: try using the `customer` object to get the email